# Stop loop after 2nd times word in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Hello guys I wrote program to add a name to array list but if you wrote 2nd times the same word the loop stop and write You gave the word twice. but I don't know where is the problem, Can you help me somebody?

```
package recurring.word;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RecurringWord {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

       Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

       while(true){
           System.out.print("Type a word: ");
            String name = reader.nextLine();

            words.add(name);

            if (words.contains(name)) {
                break;

                  }

              System.out.println("You gave the word " + name + "twice");
        }


    } 

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question. You say that it isn't running the second time if you enter a duplicate word, but then you say that's what you programmed it to do. Could you please clarify what the problem is?

Comment: my task is: Create a program that asks the user to input words until the user gives the same word twice.

and now the program add first name but after loop stop but i dont know why because i have only 1 name in array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a logic error here:

```
words.add(name);

if (words.contains(name)) {
    break;
}
```

You add the `word` to the `ArrayList` and then immediately after, if it is in the `ArrayList` you `break` out of the loop. You need to switch it to:

```
if (words.contains(name)) {
    break;
}
words.add(name);
```

This will check to see if you already typed in the word *before* you add it to the list.

Also you have the print statement inside the `while` loop which is not what you want. Move it outside:

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
String name;
while(true){
   System.out.print("Type a word: ");
   name  = reader.nextLine();        

   if (words.contains(name)) {
       break;
   }
   words.add(name);


}
System.out.println("You gave the word " + name + " twice");
```